# How to find the distribution of $X+Y$ from joint pgf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that X and Y have joint probability generating function(pgf)
$$G_{X,Y}(s,t)=e^{\alpha(s-1)+\beta(t-1)+\gamma(st-1)}$$
the question ask me to find the marginal distribution of $X$,$Y$ and the distribution of $X+Y$

For marginal distribution of $X$, when $t=1$ $$G_{X,Y}(s,1)=G_X(s)=e^{(\alpha+\gamma)(s-1)}$$ which is the pgf of poisson distribution, and similar for $s=1$.
Then X,Y follows poisson distribution with parameter $\alpha+\gamma$ and $\beta+\gamma$ respectively.
My question is that how I can find the distribution of $X+Y$?

Comment: If $G_X$ and $G_Y$ are the probability-generating functions of $X$ and $Y$, then $G_XG_Y$ is the probability-generating function of $X+Y$.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your comment! I know the formula holds when X,Y are independent. But the independence of X,Y is not given in the question. Can I still apply the formula ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick

$$G_{X+Y}(s) = \mathbb{E}\bigl(s^{X+Y}\bigr) = \mathbb{E}(s^Xs^Y) = G_{X,Y}(s,s) = e^{\alpha(s-1)+\beta(s-1)+\gamma(s^2-1)}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y=k) = G^{(k)}_{X+Y}(0) = \left.\frac{d^k}{ds^k}\,e^{\alpha(s-1)+\beta(s-1)+\gamma(s^2-1)}\right|_{s=0}$$

All you need to do is to find a closed form for the k-th derivative evaluated in zero, which may be difficult though.